# Inconsistent timing and performance

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, numerical-methods

As a learning experiment I decided to test out some numerical method exercises. I wanted to test the difference in computation time in order to visualize the difference. However, upon trying to run the program I'm coming across some strange behavior. I'm running an old version of node if that matters (v8.9.4). The code is below.

```
let n = 1000000000;
polyEvalTimeTest(n, "power", f_pow);
polyEvalTimeTest(n, "mult", f_mult);

function polyEvalTimeTest(n, name, f){
    
    const startTime = Date.now();

    for(let i = 0; i < n; i++){
        let x = i * 0.001;
        let y = f(x);
    }

    const endTime = Date.now();
    console.log(name + " : " + (endTime - startTime));

}

function f_pow(x){
    return 2.0 * Math.pow(x, 4) + 3.0 * Math.pow(x, 3) - 3.0 * Math.pow(x, 2) + 5.0 * x - 1;
}

function f_mult(x){
    return 2.0 * x*x*x*x + 3.0 * x*x*x - 3.0 * x*x + 5.0 * x - 1;
}
```

When I run as above, I get output similar to

```
power : 621
mult : 11962
```

Which is obviously not correct. When I comment out the "power", test I get output similar to

```
mult : 620
```

When I comment out the "mult" test, I get output similar to

```
power : 623
```

If I reverse the calls to `polyEvalTimeTest()`, I get output similar to

```
mult : 619
power : 40706
```

Obviously I am missing something. Can someone explain to me what is causing this behavior to me?

If I just create an copy-paste version without using `polyEvalTimeTest()`, it works fine.

Comment: My stab-in-the-dark is that there was some optimization of `polyEvalTimeTest` (don't know what) that is completely exploded when the eval function is changed. You might be able to narrow down that assumption by playing games w/ where the eval fns are defined, or by passing in a flag that chooses between the two, or... :shrug: Or by creating two identical `polyEvalTimeTestN` fns and passing in the eval fns to only one of them, e.g., `pETT1(xxx, f_pow)` and `pETT2(xxx, f_mult)` and see if that changes the results.

Comment: Creating two identical functions for `pETT()` does avoid the timing issue, but that still keeps the code from being reusable.

Comment: I was trying to qualify it, e.g., the "what is causing this behavior" part. Next easiest step is to play w/ the optimization CLI options to see which option(s) are the culprit. I would also try on a non-old version, because that's old enough to make a huge difference.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm at work right now, so I don't have any ability to update on my own. Maybe I'll mess around with it tonight.

Comment: That is a good point at it being so old. I just tried it in the chrome dev tools, and it works fine. I think I'll just chalk it up to an issue in the old version.